# How to write conditional DynamoDB query in java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am new to AWS and I need help writing a DynamoDB query for specific conditions.

Here is my requirement:
Table name = Employee with schema Id(indexed), name, salary, doj, pincode.

I need to query employees where salary > 20K and salary < 30K and doj > 2016 and doj < 2018.

I tried with QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec() using [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html) but not able to make it work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What query spec did you try and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try write conditional queries using the filter conditions in Scan method in Dynamodb and if you need to use Query method then you need to have GSI(Global secondary index) to query the non indexed keys which has been specified as GSI in your table definition.